# Accented character in HTML META description

Tags: html, xhtml, character-encoding

**ISSUES**

The website I develop has accented characters (mainly ö,ü). The charset is utf-8.
The accented characters are properly displayed in the browser but when I view the source in the META description there are question marks instead of the accented characters.
Why this happens?

I switched to `ISO-8859-1` then in the META description the accented characters are OK but on the website there are undefined characters. (if I use 'Entity Codes' then the accented characters are OK but in that case I will have to make a lot of changes to my code so I would like solve it with UTF-8 if possible.)

My doctype is: `xhtml1-transitional`

Comment: Which editor do you use to view the source?

Comment: It might be due to the server setting, what encoding does it send? Check with curl -I or similar.

Comment: Actually, I view the source in Firefox by Right clicking-> View Page Source

Comment: If you have a live link for page, I could help. Such problems are sometimes related to lack of proper UTF-8 encoding (in source file).

Comment: If you view the source code of the page there is the error in the 8th line. <meta name="description" content="InErMa - Institut f�r ErfolgsManagement" />

Comment: It should be <meta name="description" content="InErMa - Institut für ErfolgsManagement" />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your page has a mix of character encodings. The visible text is UTF-8 but the question mark characters in the description are not. To fix, just change the description to use UTF-8 characters throughout.

Comment: Can you specify how to do that?

Comment: I already added this <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> as you can see.

Comment: The problem is not the charset declaration, it's the actual characters in the file. The characters in the description that are not displaying correctly are not encoded as UYF-8. Open the file, delete and retype those characters, then make sure that the file is saved as UTD-8.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I checked the file and it was encoded as ANSI, when changed to UTF-8 and retyped the character it worked.